Android App without Android Studio or React Native?
I'm new to Android Application Development, so please correct me if I'm saying something dumb.
I've been trying to develop an Android App since a month now, but I haven't made any progress.
In the first two week, I tried React Native with Expo, but I cancelled that out because:

I tried to bundle my App into an apk. After debugging and searching for OS and Software error fixes, I managed to squeeze out an .apk, but it failed to run correctly on my Android Device. JS simply seems to complicated to me, because of it's oversimplifications. I'm a C++ developer, so I'm used to have complete control over my programs, especially the memory. I miss that in JS.
After React Native with Expo, I tried Android Studio. Had to abandon that too, because:
Android Studio simply doesn't like AMD CPUs. I tried to do all Hyper-V and other stuff, but none of that did work, as the Emulator simply didn't even show up.
Trying to connect to my physical device:


Scanning the QR code, I got an error on my Desktop saying that it wasn't able to connect.




Pairing trough PIN, my Computer wasn't even able to find my Phone, even tough they were connected to the same network, without any proxy or VPN.



In summary, I'm looking for something which works out-of-the-box with options for Firebase and Networking.
Here are my Hardware Specs:

OS: Windows 10 Pro, fully updated
RAM: 48GB DDR4
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 5600 with Raden Graphics
GPU: RTX4060 8GB
ROM: 1TB nvme, 500GB free.


Why would you be scanning a QR code to connect your device to Android Studio?  You hook it up by USB and the app that actually talks to it (adb, which is called by Android Studio) doesn't care if it's a real device or an emulator.  At any rate, Android Studio is not needed to develop in Java, Kotlin, or C++.  All of those work via the command line if necessary, Android Studio just calls the command line functionality for you.

You can write code in C++ via the NDK.  It's not recommended.  You will still be calling Java funcitonality frequently via JNI, and your app may have unusual performance issues as a result.

Qt apps can be deployed for Android. In this case you would use Qt Creator instead of Android Studio

you can try genymotion and virtual box this is a virtual sim, great for amd. also if you dont like JS and react you should use Flutter along with kotlin and java. flutter is a UI kit and uses Dart which is closer to C++ and it works great with firebase too. plus with flutter you can run on ios and web

I believe that to create an android App using C++ without android studio, it involves a lot of manual setup process. You can use command-line tools like CMake, AndroidNDK, and Android Debug Bridge. You can use tools like Visual Studio Code as a Code Editor.

You can setup environment variable to make your Android SDK, NDK etc. easily accessible from the terminal
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/path/to/your/android-sdk


It can be a challenging task to build Android Apps using C++ from scratch. If you feel stuck during the development. Feel free to ask me.
